# discord.py discord import broken +code randomly "not in use" etc

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm starting to get fed up with discord.py as nothing seems to work.
This is my code

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$")


@client.command()
async def load(extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
    print("Loaded")


@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
    print("Unloaded")

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

My client.run is slightly below. I can't post the picture, but my **"import discord"** at the top is greyed out (APPARENTLY NOT IN USE EVEN THOUGH THERES CODE RIGHT THERE). I get error messages that either "ctx" or "extension" is a required argument, but it's clearly there and wherever theres "ctx" it's also greyed out for some fucking reason. Things in my cog file don't seem to work either. The unload and load commands also have required arguments that just seem to disappear on launch. I'm overly frustrated and I have no idea what's wrong. Theres probably other things going wrong but I'm too flustered to include them. Please help.

Comment: help me please someone

Comment: If you're getting error messages, include them in the post.  Saying "I'm getting errors" is not much help.

Comment: if you read the post you'd understand btw

Comment: I read the post, and I do not understand.  `name` is the only required argument to `load_extension()` and `unload_extension()`, so I have no idea what function would be asking for `ctx` or `extension`.

Comment: I included it in my comment below the "answer" whichever argument I pass second, comes up as missing in an error message. also I do have a "ctx" passed though my load command like it is in the unload one, I just forgot to include it.

Answer (score 0):

`import discord` is greyed out because you do not use it, you use `commands`, which is imported on a separate line.

Anyways, it's hard to diagnose your issue when you're very unspecific.

Comment: I said it in the original post but fine. if I try to use unload I get an error saying "extension is a required argument that is missing" but I included it in my code.